NFS is too slow
I need your help.
The server which my senior built had some problem, so I reinstalled server. 
Former one and now one have been built with same way.
Clients get bootloader from the server from tftp. 
And using nfs-server.service, clients mount on storage in the server.
This is my /etc/exports file
# /etc/exports
/home   10.100.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/tftpboot/nfsroot   10.100.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_root_squash)

and this is my /tftpboot/nfsroot/etc/fstab
# /tftpboot/nfsroot/etc/fstab
10.100.0.1:/tftpboot/nfsroot    /    nfs    defaults    0 0 
10.100.0.1:/home    /home    nfs    defaults     0 0 
none    /dev/pts    devpts    gid=5,mode=620    0 0
none    /proc    proc    defaults    0 0
none    /dev/shm    tmpfs    defaults    0 0
none    /sys    sysfs    defaults    0 0


20~30 clients share the same root /tftpboot/nfsroot/.
The previous server had no speed problem, but newly built server is too slow in clients. At first, I thought it was a firewall problem, so I temporarily stopped firewalld.service but the problem has not been solved.
What can I try to solve the problem? If you need more information, please let me know.
I appreciate with your help.

which client and server versions are used?
